# Unable to resignFirstResponder from UITextField

Tags: ios

Do you know(can you see) why I can not resign from FirstResponder and hide the keyboard?

FYI: Xcode 9

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.text.delegate = self
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapFunction))
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    var keyboardInputEnabled = true
    @objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if self.keyboardInputEnabled {
            self.text.becomeFirstResponder()
        }else{
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            self.text.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        self.keyboardInputEnabled = !self.keyboardInputEnabled
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return self.keyboardInputEnabled
    }

    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return self.keyboardInputEnabled
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return self.keyboardInputEnabled
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `textFieldShouldEndEditing` return false the second time you run `tapFunction` which prevent it to end editing mode.

Taken from [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619592-textfieldshouldendediting)

> Normally, you would return true from this method to allow the text
>   field to resign the first responder status. You might return false,
>   however, in cases where your delegate detects invalid contents in the
>   text field. Returning false prevents the user from switching to
>   another control until the text field contains a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`self.view.endEditing(true)` for disabling keyboard